# Can't parse <content:encoded> from RSS

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing, rss, urlfetch

This is what RSS looks like: https://reddit.0qz.fun/r/dankmemes/top.json

My script perfectly parses "title", "description" and other items tags from the RSS. But it doesn't parse "content:encoded".

I tried this:

```
item.getChild("content:encoded").getText();
```

And this:

```
item.getChild("encoded").getText();
```

And this (found on Stackoverflow):

```
item.getChild("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/","encoded").getText();
```

But nothing works... Could you help me?

Comment: Can't you just get json instead?

Comment: @TheMaster how?

Answer (score 2):

The [namespace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/namespace) is important for the [`getChild`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getChild(String,Namespace)) and similar methods to parse the content successfully.

Your third example is close, but you have the parameter order backwards, and you need to use the [`XmlService.getNamespace`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#getNamespace(String)) method, not a raw string. (The signature is `getChild(string, namespace)`, not `getChild(string, string)`.)

This one is tricky as the namespace should be included for some of the elements, and not for others.  I am not an XML expert, so I don't know if this is expected behavior or not. The minimal example script below does find and log the text of the `<content:encoded>` elements using `getChild`, but I was only able to figure out when to include or exclude the namespace through trial and error.  (If anyone has further info on why this is, please let me know in the comments.)

```js
function logContentEncoded() {
  const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://reddit.0qz.fun/r/dankmemes/top.json");
  const document = XmlService.parse(result.getContentText());
  const root = document.getRootElement();
  const namespace = XmlService.getNamespace("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");
  const channel = root.getChild("channel"); // fails if namespace is included
  const item = channel.getChild("item"); // fails if namespace is included
  const encoded = item.getChild("encoded", namespace); // fails if namespace is EXCLUDED
  console.log(encoded.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this library to the project: `1Mc8BthYthXx6CoIz90-JiSzSafVnT6U3t0z_W3hLTAX5ek4w0G_EIrNw`

You can scrape the page. With this code, i.e., You can get the first content of `<content:encoded>` tags.

```
function getDataFromJson() {
  var url = "https://reddit.0qz.fun/r/dankmemes/top.json";
  var fromText = '<content:encoded>';
  var toText = '</content:encoded>';
  
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var scraped = Parser
  .data(content)
  .from(fromText)
  .to(toText)
  .build();
  Logger.log(scraped);
  return scraped;
}
```